# Find all $n \in \mathbb{Z}_{>0}$ such that $n^2+a \mid n^3+a$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Could anyone advise me how to find all $n \in \mathbb{Z}_{>0}$ such that $n^2+a $ divides $ n^3+a,$ where $a \in \mathbb{Z} \setminus \{0\}$ is fixed ?

I have checked it is necessary that $n^2+a $ divides $ a^2+a,$ i.e $-a \leq n \leq a.$ Am I on the right track? Thank you.

Comment: how did you get that result?

Answer (score 2):

$n^2+a$ divides $n^3+na$ and so it divides $n^3+a$ if and only if $n^2+a$ divides the difference, which is $na-a$. Of course you want positive integer solutions, and for $n>a$ we have $n^2+a\geq na+a> na-a$.

Hence you have to try for values between $1$ and $a$.

Comment: It will always hold for $n=1$.  Also, while $n$ is positive, $a$ could be negative: are you taking this into consideration?

Answer (score 0):

$n^2+a \mid n^3+a-n(n^2+a)$, therefore the divisibility is equivalent to
$$
n^2+a \mid a(n-1).
$$
Define the integer $k$ such that $a=n^2-k$. Then, equivalently
$$
k\mid (n^2-k)(n-1) \Leftrightarrow k\mid n^3-n^2.
$$
It follows that all solutions $(n,a)$ are in the form $(n,n^2-k)$, where $k$ stands for a divisor of $n^3-n^2$.